# Generate a report in google analytics to see demographic and browser info for bounced users

Tags: google-analytics, bounce-rate, bounce

Im trying to get the bounce rate down for a site manage, among various avenues im exploring id like to see a report from google analytics that shows me all stats for bounced users : browser, OS, device, location etc..

I can see how to get this report for all visitors in general, but not for the only the bounced users.. any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics offers a built-in segment of Bounced users, which can be applied to various reports, including the ones containing the stats, you are looking for. If you are looking into this information especially on session level, you can create your own segment for this. Just apply the following condition to a new segment under Advanced tab of new segment dialog:

`Filter -> Sessions -> Include
Bounces = 1`